# ¿En qué forma debo usar la funcion ajax de javascript para mandar datos desde javascript a php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, postgresql

Tengo este problema con mi formulario, tengo que recibir datos e ingresarlos a la base de datos y con la fecha de nacimiento calcular la edad, pero tengo que hacerlo usando `javascript` y `php`, mi programa recibe los datos con `javascript` y quiero mandar esos datos a mi codigo en `php` que hace la conexion y el calculo.

Mi index:

Formulario

```
 -->

<script language="javascript" src="js/recibir.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <form>
   Nombre(s):
<input type="text" id="snombres">
 <br><br>
   Apellido Paterno:
<input type="text" id="sapellidoP">
 <br><br>
   Apellido Materno:
<input type="text" id="sapellidoM">
<br><br>
   Fecha de nacimiento:
<input type="date" id="ifechaNac">
<br><br>
edad: 
<br><br>


<!--se mandan los datos-->
<input type="button" value="Confirmar" onClick="recibir()" >

<!--se limpian los campos-->
<input type="reset">



</form>
```

y los recibo con javascript:

```
function recibir()
{
var snombre =document.getElementById('snombres').value;
var sapellidoP =document.getElementById('sapellidoP').value;
var sapellidoM =document.getElementById('sapellidoM').value;
var ifechaNac =document.getElementById('ifechaNac').value;
}
```

Quiero usar ajax para mandar estos datos a mi archivo php:

```
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<?php 
include_once("calcularEdad.php");


//recibe los datos del formulario     

$snombres = $_REQUEST['snombres'];
$sapellidoP = $_REQUEST['sapellidoP'];
$sapellidoM = $_REQUEST['sapellidoM'];
$ifechaNac = $_REQUEST['ifechaNac'];



//conexion a la base de datos

$dbconn3 = pg_connect("host=ipProyecto port=5432 dbname=DBname user=UserName password=passWord");



//Manda a llamar a la funcion calcularEdad.

$iedad = calcularEdad($ifechaNac);

//Guarda los datos en la tabla: tablaFormulario
pg_query("INSERT INTO tablaFormulario(nombres,apellidoP,apellidoM,fechaNac,edad)
                  VALUES ('$snombres', '$sapellidoP', '$sapellidoM', '$ifechaNac','$iedad')"); 

?> 
</html>
```

de antemano Gracias!

Comment: Saito, ¿puedes ser un poco más especifico? ¿Hay algun error que estes experimentando? [en este enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) puedes encontrar mas informacion de Ajax y Javascript.

Comment: veras, mi archivo js recibe los datos, y mi archivo php hace la conexion y los inserta, lo que necesito es saber como pasarle los valores a a mi archivo php desde mi archivo js

Comment: Saito, has logrado hacer que funcione? Si he respondido tu pregunta, no olvides marcarla como respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es añadir el siguiente código a la funcion `recibir`:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhttp.open("POST", "tu_archivo.php", true);
xhttp.send("snombres="+snombre+"&sapellidoP="+sapellidoP+"&sapellidoM="+sapellidoM+"&ifechaNac="+str(ifechaNac));
```

En tu archivo PHP, lo unico que debes cambiar es `$_REQUEST` por `$_POST` ya que se esta usando el metodo post para mandar la información. Quedaria algo asi:

```
$snombres = $_POST['snombres'];
$sapellidoP = $_POST['sapellidoP'];
$sapellidoM = $_POST['sapellidoM'];
$ifechaNac = $_POST['ifechaNac'];
```

Recuerda cambiar el nombre del archivo php por el tuyo.

Como un añadido a la pregunta, te recomiendo usar algun framework de Javascript, porque a veces puede ser un poco engorroso usar javascript puro. Por ejemplo, usando JQuery, la funcion Ajax se reduce a lo siguiente:

```
$.post("tu_archivo.php",
  {
     snombres: snombre,
     sapellidoP: sapellidoP,
     sapellidoM: sapellidoM,
     ifechaNac: ifechaNac
  });
```